# Change avatar with vue.js without refresh?

Tags: vue.js

I have this in view:

```
<div class="seller_image" :style="{background: 'url(' + user_credentials.avatar +')', backgroundSize: 'cover ', display: 'block'}">

</div>
```

In vue i have this:

```
setAvatar:function(x,y,w,h){
          this.setAvatarLoader = true;
         var data = new FormData();
         this.x1 = $('#x1').val();
         this.y1 = $('#y1').val();
         this.w = $('#w').val();
         this.h = $('#h').val();
         this.x2 = $('#x2').val();
         this.y2 = $('#y2').val();

          data.append('avatar',this.$els.fileAvatarImage.files[0]);
          data.append('x1',this.x1);
          data.append('x2',this.x2);
          data.append('y1',this.y1);
          data.append('y2',this.y2);
          data.append('w',this.w);
          data.append('h',this.h);

          user_id = this.user_credentials.user_id;
          this.$http.post('/profile/' + user_id + '/basic_info/set_avatar',data).then(function(response){
            this.avatarImageSet = false;
            public_path = response.data.public_path;
            url_path = response.data.url_path;
            filename = response.data.filename;
            this.setAvatarLoader = false;
            this.basic_status = true;
            this.basic_success_message = response.data.successMsg;
            this.profile_image = url_path;
            this.user_credentials.avatar = url_path
            this.getAvatar();
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");


          }, function(response) {
              this.setAvatarLoader = false;
              $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                this.getAvatar();
                console.log('error');

          });
        },
```

When I refresh the page I get the avatar but in time when I set it it does not change the image.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't use both `jQuery` and `vuejs`, it makes no sense...

Comment: Yeah, this code appears to be largely ignoring the benefits of Vue in favor of doing it the old fashioned way with jQuery. jQuery code should be quite rare in a Vue app.

Comment: How to you call the `setAvatar` function?

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @click="setAvatar">Crop</button>

Comment: when i go in inspect element image is there but its not change in view.

Comment: There is a lot of mess in your code.VueJS is data-driven thing, that's mean all changes should be done in data model, and then those changes would be applied to DOM indirectly - so no direct manipulation, jQuery do a totally oposite thing, It doesn't have any kind of data model, so you are manipulating DOM directly.
It's hard to "rewrite" you code in Vue way because we don't know the your app structure.

Comment: i dont use jquery for avatar so i dont know whats the problem

Comment: @None your `setAvatar` method contains bunch of jQuery code, and this method is huge, so consider about extracting it into smaller pieces :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AWolf said, it's difficult to guess what's the problem with your code because I can see only a part of your code base.

Another possible issue could be the `url_path`. If it remains the same, will never change. So, you need to append the timestamp:

```js
this.user_credentials.avatar = url_path + '?' + Date.now()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pespantelis/fy0re26m/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, try to avoid jQuery because it's most of the time not needed and it is making things more complicated.

Please have a look at the demo below for a simple image uploader/avatar changer or at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/tgbvrLje/).

The demo just opens a file picker dialog and then the returned file is used to update the displayed image. (Posting to server is not added in the demo.)

**To your code:**

Something like `$('#x1').val()` shouldn't be done with Vue.js because in Vue you're doing that model driven.

So the only source of truth is your data model and not the stuff displayed in the DOM.

Not sure what you're trying to do with the x1,y1, ... code. That's not clear from your snippet with-out the html markup.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      user_credentials: {
        avatar: 'https://unsplash.it/100/100'
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeAvatar() {
      const input = document.createElement('input');
      let self = this;
      input.setAttribute("type", "file");
      input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        // uploading code from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vacidesign/ja0tyj0f/
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(e) {
            // image is loaded callback
            self.user_credentials.avatar = e.target.result;
            // here you can post the data to your backend...
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
      })
      input.click(); // opening dialog

      return false; // avoiding navigation
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.seller_image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="seller_image" :style="{background: 'url(' + user_credentials.avatar +')', backgroundSize: 'cover ', display: 'block'}">

  </div>
  <button @click="changeAvatar()">
    Change
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not working as expected...sometimes image is change sometimes not

Comment: it's difficult to guess what's the problem with your code because I can see only a part of your code base. One possible problem could be the context of `this`. Please check if `this` inside the promise callbacks is right. Probably not, so you could try to use self variable to have the correct context. (see usage in my demo)